# JConsole tomcat connectivity does not work on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: tomcat, service, tomcat6, windows-server-2008-r2, jconsole

I am having a problem connecting to Tomcat 6 running as a service on Windows Server 2008 R2. Here are the details of my setup.

32 Bit JDK 1.6._23
64 Bit Windows Server 2008 R2

My jakarta service log shows that I am setting the jvm properties to turn on jmx remote access to the JVM

```
[2010-12-22 23:22:21] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[6] -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
[2010-12-22 23:22:21] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[7] -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999
[2010-12-22 23:22:21] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[8] -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
[2010-12-22 23:22:21] [447  javajni.c] [debug] Jvm Option[9] -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I am running jconsole on the same machine that is running tomcat so I am not trying to connect remotely and should
not have any problems with ports I even turned off the windows firewall on the machine to make sure it was not getting
in the way

systernals tcpview shows that tomact6.exe is listening on port 8999

I am running tomact6 service as the user pmtomact

I am running jconsole as the user Administrator

on the jconsole I tried localhost:8999 and it tries to connect for a while then reports that it can can not connect.

I tried running tomcat as user administrator just starting from the startup.bat with the proper jmx paramters and it does not work either.

I tried running jconsole as pmtomcat user still no luck connecting

I tried creating a directory under C:\Users\pmtomcat\AppData\Local\Temp\hsperfdata_pmtomcat and checked that the directory was writable by the pmtomcat user still it does not work.

Any ideas of how I can troubleshoot this problem, it is driving me crazy?

Comment: I tested my tomcat setup on Vista 64 bit machine with identical setup for JDK and tomcat and Jconsole works so the issue seems to be with Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more googling led me this problem repot http://tai-dev.blog.co.uk/2010/03/26/glassfish-jmx-and-windows-web-server-2008-can-play-together-with-a-few-tweaks-here-s-how-plus-bonus-jconsole-config-info-8251001/

and the fix was to add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 to my command line options for the service. I have no idea why this setting fixes the problem but it does.